# How to get only numbers and math operators in string?

Tags: c#, math, calculator, calc

im making basic C# calculator.
It uses user message and detects if it contains math operators to identify it user sends a math problem.
But problem is when user sends "br + uh" program crashes because "Cannot find column [br]".
I need to filter words from user message or i want to get only numbers(int, double, float etc.) and math operators. Please help
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8C1k.png)

Comment: You're using DataTable to evaluate the expression. You should catch its exceptions  and use that as the means to detect if it's a valid expression. Also, I suggest pasting your code into the question (not linking to a screenshot of it).

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code. Instead post the code in your question with formatted code blocks

Answer (score 1):

A super simple way to at least not make it crash is look into `TryParse` methods.
Even better would be e.g using regex and writing a nice regex so your calculator only accepts input it'll be able to process.

Answer (score 0):

You're using DataTable to evaluate the expression (which is neat). You should catch its exceptions and use that as the means to detect if it's a valid expression

```
var msg = e.Message.Text;
try 
{
    var output = new DataTable().Compute(msg, null).ToString();
    // It was a valid expression - do something with the result
    Send(output);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Not a valid expression
    // Do something in this error case such as providing the detail back to the user
    SendError(ex.Message);
}
```